# Summation over permutation: $\sum_{\sigma \in S_N} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^N x_{i+\sigma(i)}$

Tags: summation, permutation

Let $N$ be a natural number, and $S_N$ be the symmetric group over $\{1, \ldots, N\}$. I want to compute
$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_N} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^N x_{i+\sigma(i)}$$
for small $N$ using Mathematica. Here, $x_2, \ldots, x_{2N}$ are variables, which one may implement in the form `x[i]`, and $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) = \pm 1$ if $\sigma$ is an odd (resp. even) permutation.

How to implement the sum? After searching other posts in this site, I found `Permutations[Range[3]]` useful, but I cannot implement $\prod_{i=1}^N x_{i+\sigma(i)}$ and summation over the permutation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[n_] := Total[Signature[#] Apply[Times, MapIndexed[x[#2[[1]] + #1] &, #]] & /@
           Permutations[Range[n]]]

f[1]
(*    x[2]    *)

f[2]
(*    -x[3]^2 + x[2] x[4]    *)

f[3]
(*    -x[4]^3 + 2 x[3] x[4] x[5] - x[2] x[5]^2 - x[3]^2 x[6] + x[2] x[4] x[6]    *)
```

A much easier calculation would be through the matrix determinant:

```
g[n_] := Det[Table[x[i + j], {i, n}, {j, n}]]

Table[f[n] == g[n], {n, 9}] // Expand
(*    {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}    *)
```

For fun we can write this determinant as

```
G = Det[x@+##&~Array~{#,#}]&
```

to save some bits and confuse the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Both methods are very elegant!

Comment: @eigenvalue  The x[i+j] reminded me of Toeplitz matrices (or circulant matrices it was vague in my head) and indeed after some searching, it's connected as it's a Hankel matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix.  Thus I suppose one could calculate the determinant in O(n^2) time using the  Levinson algorithm given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix

Comment: I wanted to see if ChatGPT could identify the matrix. It first incorrectly stated it was a Toeplitz matrix. I told it why it was incorrect, and it then said it was a Cauchy matrix and I told it why it's incorrect in general and then it finally said it was a Hankel matrix. I feel that's somewhat telling of how it operates. I assume it did not read a lot about Hankel matrices and so It picked out a more common element in a semantic cluster of similar-looking concepts. That feels similar to how people remember by association and tend to remember the stuff we saw more often.

Comment: @eigenvalue just to clarify, when I said one could use the Levinson algorithm, I meant on the Toepliz factor after using the decomposition in the Hankel Wikipedia page. Perhaps there is a modification of the Levinson algorithm that would allow implementing it directly on the Hankel matrix.

Comment: @userrandrand yes I was looking up all the Toeplitz- and Hankel-matrix pages but could not find a match for this problem, and so I left it as an explicit `Table`. Getting the Levinson algorithm set up for this determinant could be an interesting problem for the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: @userrandrand I look forward to the day when a system like GPT can provide deep insight; but we're not there yet.

Comment: @Roman there is a paper that shows the mathematical capabilities of chatgpt (not much): https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.13867.pdf. Basically, it shows that it's fairly good at finding math names from descriptions (which is quite useful for searching through the literature). But its proof-finding capabilities and usage of math are not too good. There is also the sparks of AGI paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.12712 that shows GPT solving an olympiad question (the answer looks like a brute force answer but I did not read everything)

Comment: Basically, it's not smart enough yet but if I understood correctly it becomes more intelligent the bigger the model is and the more data you give it. From the interviews I saw, the company does not seem to be facing any serious problems that would prevent them from upgrading for a while.

Comment: Other than that there are the machine learning tree search algorithms of meta (facebook) and around 2018 I saw a conference about using neural networks for exploring the string theory landscape. Not sure where that project is now.

Comment: by "mathematical capabilities of chatgpt (not much)" I meant chatgpt does not have a lot of mathematical capabilities. I am also interested in seeing how a gpt 5 or gpt 6 will use the wolfram plugin and whether the company will increase the amount of training on the Wolfram language.